# Could I reference field of request in text summary of endpoint in a swagger spec? In therefore go-swagger?

Tags: swagger, go-swagger

I have the following swagger spec for the endpoint:

```
records-by-time:
    post:
      operationId: idOfRecordsByTimeEndpoint
      parameters:
      - in: body
        name: Body
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/RecordsByTimeRequest'
      responses:
        "200":
          $ref: '#/responses/RecordsByTimeResponse'
      summary: 'Return records where fieldName value lies between #/definitions/RecordsByTimeRequest/left_bound and right_bound.'
      tags:
      - get-records
```

And I have the following definition

```
definitions:
  RecordsByTimeRequest:
    properties:
      driver_name:
        type: string
        x-go-name: DriverName
      field_name:
        type: string
        x-go-name: FieldName
      left_bound:
        format: date-time
        type: string
        x-go-name: LeftBound
      right_bound:
        format: date-time
        type: string
        x-go-name: RightBound
      table_name:
        type: string
        x-go-name: TableName
```

Could I make **left_bound** in the summary references **left_bound** in the definition of the request, maybe a link to the field in the request definition field? If I can, how to apply it to go-swagger comments.